# Do purchased themes need to be fully built from the ground up?

Tags: theming

Really naïve newbie question....

I am brand new to Drupal after working in Wordpress for quite a while.  We bought a custom agricultural theme for $75 - it looked perfect for my project at work.  The sample had all the right stuff with content placed in areas I can customize to my project.

However, now that I have downloaded it, it is just "bare bones."  The structure for the content and images is nowhere to be found.  The drop-down menu isn't horizontal, the whole structure is absent. I thought this would be easier.  Do I have to build everything in Dreamweaver? Did I miss something? Are the themes merely "suggested formats?"

Comment: A sites theme and a sites configuration are two very different things.  As @KyleTaylored mentioned, check if there is a DB dump or install profile that was included with the theme as a starting point. It is very common for this to be available with a purchased theme.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a proprietary theme, and should be asked theme seller's customer support. Also, answer will be different from theme to theme, so this question has no value for other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

where did you buy the theme from? Do they provide installation instructions or usage instructions? Did it ship with any additional modules to enable configuration?

A theme is basically styled blocks, views, nodes, regions. You need to place your content into Regions of the theme for it to show up like their example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you buy a theme like that, it will come shipped with a database that will start you off with all the default content and settings. Look back in the download and see if you can find any kind of .sql.gz file anywhere.

Sometimes they would use like an install profile so when you install Drupal, you would pick the custom profile name instead of the standard or minimal installation.